# How to use primary key with partitioning table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a table that I have partitioned, but I don't know how to add a primary key to it.

Indeed, the following script does not work

```
CREATE TABLE commande
(
id INT IDENTITY,
date_commande DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
CONSTRAINT pk_id_commande PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
ON scheme_partition_date(date_commande);
GO
```

It produces the following error:
"command_date" is a partition column of the index "pk_command_id'. The partition columns of a single index must be a subset of the index key.

So I create the table without primary key.
And I want to modify it to add a primary key index:

```
ALTER TABLE commande
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_commande_id PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (id);
```

But it produce the same error :

"command_date" is a partition column of the index "pk_command_id'. The partition columns of a single index must be a subset of the index key.

I see someone propose me this solution : [Partition columns for a unique index must be a subset of the index key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633878/partition-columns-for-a-unique-index-must-be-a-subset-of-the-index-key-error)

But this is a mistake to me.

Imagine that you want to partition a table based on criteria such as archiving.

For example, table records that are not archived go to partition one and the others go to partition two.
Let's say that this archiving field is called "archived".

Want to create a partition based on this field, such as :

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION fct_archived(int)
AS RANGE FOR VALUES (0,1);
GO GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME scheme_archived
AS PARTITION fct_archived TO (FILEGROUP01, FILEGROUP02, FILEGROUP03);
GO GO
```

This implies that my table includes in its primary key the column "archived".

Doing so would be a violation of the second normal form, since the non-key columns of the table would be functionally dependent on only part of the key.

That is why I would like to be helped to find a solution that does not violate any normal form.

Up anyone already experience the problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partition columns for a unique index must be a subset of the index key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633878/partition-columns-for-a-unique-index-must-be-a-subset-of-the-index-key-error)

Comment: The column in the partition needs to be in the index.

Comment: By meaning "to be in the index" you mean the pk ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to create the non-clustered primary key index on the same partition scheme as the table, but its key columns don't contain the partition key.

By default indexes are created on the same Data Space (ie Filegroup or Partition Scheme) as the table.

So you have to explicitly place the primary key index on a filegroup. Eg

```
CREATE TABLE commande
(
  id INT IDENTITY,
  date_commande DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT pk_id_commande PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (id) ON [Primary]
)
ON scheme_partition_date(date_commande);
```

BTW this will create Heap table, which is probably the worst option.  You probably want to choose between a clustered index including `date_commande` or a Clustered Columnstore for storage of the main table.